# Overriding onPostExecute() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to learn how to work with AsyncTask.  I have code in the `doInBackground` that returns a String array, and a callback that invokes an interface to return it to the MainActivity.  I am successfully executing the AsyncTask.

The problem is: trying to return the array via onPostExecute I'm getting an arguments error; it won't accept the array.  How do I use the `onPostExecute` method to return the value `feeds`? I have tried to change the result of `doInBackground` but that wouldn't accept an array either.

Here is the interface called in MainActivity:

```
interface DownloadFinishedListener {
void notifyDataRefreshed(String[] feeds);}
```

Here is the callback:

```
try {
        mCallback = (DownloadFinishedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement DownloadFinishedListener");
    }
```

and here is the AsyncTask:

```
public class DownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        downloadTweets(params);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        mCallback.notifyDataRefreshed(s); //trying to send back feeds
    }

    // Simulates downloading Twitter data from the network


    private String[] downloadTweets(Integer resourceIDS[]) {
        final int simulatedDelay = 2000;
        String[] feeds = new String[resourceIDS.length];
        try {
            for (int idx = 0; idx < resourceIDS.length; idx++) {
                InputStream inputStream;
                BufferedReader in;
                try {
                    // Pretend downloading takes a long time
                    Thread.sleep(simulatedDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(
                        resourceIDS[idx]);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String readLine;
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

                while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    buf.append(readLine);
                }

                feeds[idx] = buf.toString();

                if (null != in) {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return feeds;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is: trying to return the array via onPostExecute I'm
>   getting an arguments error; it won't accept the array

You need to pass String Array as last generic argument to AsyncTask which is return type of `doInBackground` and argument type of `onPostExecute`.

Do following changes :

**1.** extend `AsyncTask` as:

```
public class DownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String[]>
```

**2.** Change `doInBackground` method return type from `String` to `String[]` :

```
 @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        downloadTweets(params);
        return downloadTweets(params);
    }
```

**3.** Change `onPostExecute` paramter type from `String` to `String[]` :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        mCallback.notifyDataRefreshed(s); //trying to send back feeds
   }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried using `String...` and that gave me all sorts of errors.  'String[]' seems to have taken care of it, as well as the other suggested edits.

Comment: Can I get clarification on point number 2?  If you call `downloadTweets(params);
        return downloadTweets(params);` that will call the method twice, right?

Comment: @Dithanial: Yes, return String[] Array from `doInBackground` which is returned from downloadTweets method

Comment: Ok, but I don't need to call the `downloadTweets()` method twice.  I could just do it once with `return downloadTweets(params);` right?

Comment: @Dithanial: Yes right. also add `null` check `params` value

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `String[]` as last argument in your `AsyncTask` not just `String` as you are doing and your `AsyncTask` should look like similar to this:

```
public class DownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        return downloadTweets(params);;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        mCallback.notifyDataRefreshed(s); //trying to send back feeds
    }
}
```

Comment: Also need to change return type of `doInBackground` method from `String` to `String[]`